# configure SAXParser to process XML document with a DOCTYPE on WildFly

Tags: java, jaxb, wildfly, resteasy, saxparser

receiving exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshalException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 10; DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.]
```

when using RestEasy client api to query RETSfule web service with DOCTYPE declaration in XML document.

**runtime environment**:

WildFly is a java EE application server by JBoss.

RestEasy is an implementation of Java EE REST/RESTFul (JAX-RS) specification by JBoss included in Wildfly.

code bellow to replicate/show the process.

XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE retsjaxb SYSTEM "retsjaxb.dtd">
<retsJaxb>
<fname>Jack</fname>
<lname>Daxter</lname>
</retsJaxb>
```

JAXB

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    public class RetsJaxb {
        private String fname;
        private String lname;
        @XmlElement
        public String getFname() {
            return fname;
        }
        public void setFname(String fname) {
            this.fname = fname;
        }
        @XmlElement
        public String getLname() {
            return lname;
        }
        public void setLname(String lname) {
            this.lname = lname;
        }
    

}
```

Java Bean to query the service

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RetsClient {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("stack");
    
    public String getJaxb() {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/retesting/retsjaxb.xml").request().get();
        RetsJaxb rets = response.readEntity(RetsJaxb.class); <--- exception
        logger.info(rets.getFname());
        return "hello";
    }
    

}
```